# Generar nuevos objetos en node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Empeze a usar node.js y express para un web service, donde tengo controladores con objetos de este tipo:

```
'use strict'

var Objeto = {

    prueba: false,

    setPrueba: async (req, res) => {
        Objeto.prueba = 1
        return res.status(200).send(prueba)
    }
}
module.exports = Objeto
```

y un archivo de rutas de este tipo:

```
'use strict'
var Objeto = require('../controllers/objeto.controller')
var router = express.Router()
//get
router.get('/setPrueba/:id', Objeto.setPrueba)
module.exports = router
```

Al llamar la función setPrueba modifica la propiedad del objeto a 1, si vuelvo a hacer la llamada a la función se queda modificado el valor en 1 y necesito que este en false, esto me genera problemas de datos si varios usuarios llaman la función al mismo tiempo, trate de hacer instancias en el archivo

```
router.get('/setPrueba/:id', (req, res) => {
  const Obj = new Objeto
  Obj.setPrueba(req, res)
})
```

Esto me genera este error:

```
TypeError: Objeto is not a constructor
```

Les agradeceria su  ayuda para saber si es posible generar nuevos objetos, si necesito cambiar a clases o estoy completamente perdido en como funciona nodejs y express

Comment: Claro, el objeto es único en memoria tal como lo estás usando. La pregunta es ¿qué pretendes lograr o hacer con el objeto? ¿Cuál es su función dentro de tu programa? Por otro lado, es una aplicación de NodeJS y estamos casi en 2022, ¿porqué usas `var` en vez de `const` y `let`?

Comment: El objeto tiene la finalidad de calcular un adeudo de predial, la función es demasiado larga para ponerla completa, y tiene llamadas a otros objetos y consultas de base de datos, puse atributos en el objeto para acceder más rápido a ellos, pero note que se quedan en memoria y causan conflictos cuando se llama de nuevo la función, mi pregunta es cómo puedo hacer una instancia de este objeto con los atributos vacíos?